# how core data be saved in SQLite file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sqlite, core-data

I saved core data in SQLite file but I am wonder what's the table name in coredata I have three entities one of them is students.

While trying to using SQLite statement to read it it not enter the while

```
const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM students";

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
        NSLog(aName);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion why not enter the if statement?

Comment: As a first step, I'd find out what error code it IS returning and compare against these: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't be querying your CoreData tables directly, CoreData is there to abstract the storage from the code. You should use NSFetchRequest. But to answer your question, the table will normally be called zstudents.

Comment: zstudents not work , I am migrating as u told me from the old storage to the new one , my last questions regarding versioning

Comment: What you need to do (if it were me) would be to have the original data model, say it is called 'Model', create a new one (versioned this time) called 'Model2'. You should be able to create two NSPersistentStoreCoordinators, NSManagedObjectModel, NSManagedObjectContext etc, one set for each model. So now you can query two completely different models via CoreData. Now you can use the standard NSFetchRequest's to load the data from 'Model' and create new entities on 'Model2', and save accordingly.

Comment: I did what u told me but the relationship cause exceptions any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the table is actually called students? The core data underlying sqlite database generally has something like ZStudents as table names. You can use the free SQLite Database browser to view the schema in .sqlite files, but I have to wonder, why are writing SQL statements if you are using Core Data?

Comment: I migrate from old database to new one , also I don't have the database it's on the device

Comment: can I get all the tables in sqlite file

Comment: Download the SQLite database browser to view the schema (copy the .sqlite file from your device to your mac)

Comment: forgive me how to copy it from the device to my mac